# Moving Mysql 5.7 database from windows 7 pc to windows 10 pc Mysql 8.0. Can see database in files, but cannot open?

Tags: innodb

I have been running a Java project created using Netbeans and a Mysql 5.7 database on an HP Windows 7 PC. I moved the project to a Lenovo Windows 10 PC using Netbeans and Mysql 8.0. I can see the database with the ibdata1 file and all the tables with their .frm and .ibd files in the Program Data file just as they were in the original Windows 7 HP PC, yet neither Netbeans nor Mysql sees the database or tables. I have been working on this problem for four days and cannot find a solution. This is causing me to be very late in producing customer data. Would be very appreciative for any help you could give me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The upgrade process from 5.7 to 8.0 _must_ be accomplished with the scripts provided.  Simply moving the files will _not_ work.

Comment: Willing to pay you for your time if you could help me via phone to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

Upgrade to 8.0 on the old machine, then move *all* files in MySQL's tree to the new machine.

Plan B:

Perhaps you did not move *all* files in MySQL's tree to the new machine?

Plan C:

Instead of moving files, use mysqldump.

Plan D:

(As you did) Move the old drive to the new machine and mount it as, say, `F:.  Then do either D-1 or D-2.  After that, install 5.7 and make sure it comes up with the data.  Then Upgrade to 8.0.

Plan D-1:

Copy the my.cnf to an appropriate place on C:.  Check to see if it references C: anywhere.

Changing from C: to F: may not be all that is needed -- possibly the path has changed, too?

Plan D-2:

Copy my.cnf (see D-1).  Also copy the entire MySQL tree to some place under C:.  Again, check for any paths.

Comment: The old computer has died cannot turn it on. I removed the hard disk from the old computer and it has everything on it. I have it in a hard disk enclosure which allows me to plug it into a usb port on the new computer which sees it as "F" drive. How do I do a mysqldump using the "F" drive as the source for the database. Or am I asking the wrong question, should I be asking "is there a way to copy the database along with all the info in the mysql tree from the "F" drive to the "C" drive"?

Comment: I added Plan D.